Upgrading Microsoft.Office.Interop in C# .NET application
We have older versions of Microsoft.Office.Interop (Word, Excel) in our application and we want to upgrade to a more recent version.
We need to check if, for a given method of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, the signature has changed in a recent version of that Microsoft library.
We need to upgrade to the latest version.  So, in our C# Projects, we want to replace the references we have with references to the latest version (having installed the latest version, of course).  Rather than doing this blindly, we want to know if any of the method calls in the version we currently have have changes to their signatures or attributes, in the latest version.
Rather than doing this manually, is there some automated way to compare the method signatures of a given version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word/Excel to another version?
Trying manually, but very tedious and error-prone.

are you asking if it's possible to load two different versions of a given assembly file (for example the dll Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll) and find out if some given methods still exist on both and if their signature did change?

No, we need to upgrade to the latest version.  So, in our C# Projects, we want to replace the references we have with references to the latest version (having installed the latest version, of course).  Rather than doing this blindly, we want to know if any of the method calls in the version we currently have have changes to their signatures or attributes, in the latest version.

did you just try to change the reference to the new assembly and see the compilation errors?

@BlackRockJohnny Office interop hasn't been significantly updated in what feels like decades now - dare I ask exactly how old this "older vesion" you're running actually is?

@DiegoD -- That might be something we try.

@Dai -- I think we support 2003, 2007, 2010, and 2013 for Word and Excel interops.

why upgrade if it works fine?

@urlreader -- Not sure, it's a decision made by upper management.
